# SmartGWT: Fire on startup

Tags: startup, smartgwt

I have a situation where I have a SmartGWT app and I wish to fire some piece of code on startup. The code to be fired at startup will receive notifications from JNotify API and will populate a listgrid on the UI. Please suggest what is the best way to do it.

I am thinking on the lines of having a servlet configured in `web.xml` and doing the necessary business logic, but that sounds very low level.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to notify the client from server side. For this purpose there is a technology called server push (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) and there are many vendors out there. I would suggest the errai (http://www.jboss.org/errai/) and their event bus.

Comment: Thanks jkremser. I will explore that.